# While loop while rolling dice

Tags: python, while-loop

I am trying to use a `while` loop instead of a `for` loop while rolling dice. I do not think `elif` is right, but I cannot figure out how to use the `while` loop within this. This is what I have so far:

```
import random

def rolldiewhileloop():
    number = 10
    one = 0
    two = 0
    three = 0
    four = 0
    five = 0
    six = 0
    while number > 0:
        flip = int(random.random() * 6)
        if(flip == 1):
            one = one + 1
        elif flip == 2:
            two = two + 1
        elif flip == 3:
            three = three + 1
        elif flip == 4:
            four = four + 1
        elif flip == 5:
            five = five + 1
        elif flip == 6:
            six = six + 1

    return [one, two, three, four, five, six]
```

Answer (score 6):

In your current while loop you aren't changing the value of `number`, so this will be an infinite loop.  Since you are starting at 10 and looping until `number` is less than or equal to zero, you should probably be decrementing by one on each iteration:

```
number = 10
while number > 0:
    number -= 1
    # the rest of the loop
```

Note that `number -= 1` is equivalent to `number = number - 1`.

As a side note, instead of multiplying the result of `random.random()` it would be better to use `random.randint(1, 6)`.  Also, since you are returning an array already it would be more Pythonic to create a list of the results and modify that, rather than creating a separate variable for each possibility.  For example:

```
def rolldiewhileloop():
    results = [0] * 6
    number = 10
    while number > 0:
        number -= 1
        flip = random.randint(1, 6)
        results[flip-1] += 1
    return results
```

Comment: +1 for suggesting a better design; if you have more than 2 variables with numbers in the variable names, you almost certainly wanted a list instead.

Comment: Since you are not using `number` anywhere, why not `for _ in xrange(10)`?

Comment: @kroolik The questions specifically states that they are trying to use `while` instead of `for`.  I am assuming that they already know how to do this with `for` and they are just using `while` as a learning experience or because it is a requirement for a homework assignment.

Answer (score 1):

You need to decrement number on each pass of the while loop. Put `number -= 1` as the last line in the while loop.